# DAUs not matching. Google vs Fabric vs Facebook analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, analytics, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have Android app. Before that, I only analyzed Google Analytics. Then I decided to compare Google Analytics with Crashlytics. And DAU on Google Analytics is 28k, but on Crashlytics (fabric.io) is 19k. Why such a difference in the data? 
There screenshoots

[Google Analytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDC4a.png)

[Crashlytics(fabric)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNteX.png)

and Facebook DAU 16k

Comment: Yeah, had the same issue. couldn't get a clue of what's going on